# Druid Docker different than Local Druid

Tags: docker, docker-compose, druid

##### Goal:

I am testing out different distributions of Apache Druid. My goal is to eventually use Druid in a docker-compose setup.

##### Expected Results:

Druid 0.21.1 installed and run locally (with `start-micro-quickstart`) is the same as Druid 0.21.1 run with `docker-compose`.

##### Actual results:

Druid installed and run locally has a data ingestion page that looks like this:
[image: Local Druid Data Ingestion]

The `docker-compose.yml` from the Druid repository does not run as is because it references a druid:0.22.0 image when 0.21.1 is the latest available. When the references to 0.22.0 are changes to 0.21.0, `docker-compose` succeeds, but the data ingestion page looks like this:
[image: Docker Druid Data Ingestion]

Note specifically the lack of native support for Apache Kafka data ingestion which is what I am using.

##### Question:

Why are the local and docker builds different? Is there any way to get the `start-micro-quickstart` version in docker?

##### docker-compose.yml:

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#
version: "2.2"

volumes:
  metadata_data: {}
  middle_var: {}
  historical_var: {}
  broker_var: {}
  coordinator_var: {}
  router_var: {}
  druid_shared: {}


services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - metadata_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=FoolishPassword
      - POSTGRES_USER=druid
      - POSTGRES_DB=druid

  # Need 3.5 or later for container nodes
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.5
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOO_MY_ID=1

  coordinator:
    image: apache/druid:0.21.1
    container_name: coordinator
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - coordinator_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command:
      - coordinator
    env_file:
      - environment

  broker:
    image: apache/druid:0.21.1
    container_name: broker
    volumes:
      - broker_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    command:
      - broker
    env_file:
      - environment

  historical:
    image: apache/druid:0.21.1
    container_name: historical
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - historical_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    command:
      - historical
    env_file:
      - environment

  middlemanager:
    image: apache/druid:0.21.1
    container_name: middlemanager
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - middle_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
      - "8100-8105:8100-8105"
    command:
      - middleManager
    env_file:
      - environment

  router:
    image: apache/druid:0.21.1
    container_name: router
    volumes:
      - router_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    command:
      - router
    env_file:
      - environment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: After restarting the docker container, it now matches the local Druid build. I have no idea why I got the other version initially, but if you have this problem try restarting the container.

If anyone has a real answer please add it, but I don't want to leave this open.